# Пример TensorFlow числовая нейроная сеть

Tags: python, tensorflow

Я хотел сделать нейроную сеть на TensorFlow, которая состоит из 2 слоев (2 входных, 1 выходной). И мне нужно, например, на вход [0, 0] выход [0], [1, 0] [1], [1, 1] [0.25] итд, и чтоб обучалась.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs-l10n/blob/master/site/ru/tutorials/keras/regression.ipynb

Comment: @CrazyElf а нет ли попроще?

Comment: Ну по сути вам надо входной слой с 2 элементами и выходной с одним. Но тренировать его всё-равно надо. Надо искать пример попроще, конечно. Сходу не нашёл

Comment: @CrazyElf Я знаю что в любом случае тренировать, про все (я думаю 99.9%) примеры с картинками, а мне картинки не надо

Comment: Эта ссылка именно на задачу регрессии, просто там попутно анализ данных и всё такое ещё

Comment: Смотрите там функцию build_model

Comment: @CrazyElf Там ещё сложнее чем с картинками, а с картинками примерно понятно, но не понятно.

Comment: А кто и где обещал, что нейросети - это просто?

Comment: @passant :| с изображение более менее понятно но с числами, в которые должно легче, не фига

Comment: Ну так прочтите и разберитесь с простейшим описанием, который вам предложил выше уважаемый CrazyElf. А пример для TW на два входа  и один выход вы вряд-ли найдете, все таки это инструмент не для новичков. Кстати, в примере как раз не картинки и циферки. Правда -  больше двух, но то такое.

Comment: @passant Мне сложно изучать просто в виде текста, мне бы найти хотя бы один пример :(

Comment: @passant Если просто, можете сделать эту сеть?

Comment: @AlfaMafka  - на этом сайте помогают тем, кто что-то делает сам. А сайт "сделай за меня" гуглится по слову "фриланс".

Comment: @passant мне нужно разобраться, а я мне нужно хотябы как писать только model.fit

Comment: @AlfaMafka - если нужно глубоко разобраться - то вам в документацию: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model Если поверхностно - то пример вам привели выше.

Comment: @passant спасибо